# Definition of an algebra homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra

Our definition of an algebra homomorphism $f:A_1\to A_2$ doesn't requires $f(1_{A_1})=1_{A_2}$. Is this automatic? I don't think so, so why one doesn't include this in the definition?

Comment: Whether it is automatic depends on what else is included in the definition. And what sort of algebras? Associative unital algebras?

Comment: In my example I want to check this for an algebra hom. $kG\to\text{End}(V)$, where $kG$ is the group algebra.

Comment: It's not automatic, and it should be included in the definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the $\mathbb{Z}$-algebras $\mathbb{R}$ and $A=\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$ (the product in $A$ is componentwise). Note that $1_A=(1,1)$ and $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$ difined by $f(x)=(x,0)$ is homomorfism of algebras, but $(1,0)=f(1)\neq 1_A$.